# Playframework morphia module talk to multiple MongoDB shards or replicas

Tags: mongodb, playframework, morphia

Right now, I have configuration setting for morphia talks to one MongoDB from Play!. If I have multiple MongoDB instances (could be shards or replicas), how could I reach them from Play!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a replicaset, providing [just 1 member](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Connecting+Drivers+to+Replica+Sets) in the configuration will be enough for the Java Driver to find out the primary and secondaries.